# Suppose $gH = Hg, \forall g \in G$. does this imply that $g^{-1}Hg \subseteq H, \forall g \in G$?

Tags: abstract-algebra, group-theory

Let $G$ be a group and $H \leq G$. Suppose $gH = Hg,  \forall g \in G$. We know that this is equivalent to $gHg^{-1} \subseteq H,  \forall g \in G$ and $gHg^{-1} = H,  \forall g \in G$. However I haven't seen any textbook write what was stated in the title. Is it false?

Comment: Fix $g\in G$. Let $x\in g^{-1}Hg$. Then $x=g^{-1}hg$ for some $h\in H$. Now $hg=gh_0$ for some $h_0\in H$ by the assumption. So $x=g^{-1}gh_0=h_0\in H$.

Answer (score 2):

The following statements are equivalent:

(i) $gH = Hg$ for all $g \in G$;

(ii) $gHg^{-1} = H$ for all $g \in G$;

(iii) $gHg^{-1} \subseteq H$ for all $g \in G$.

> *Proof*.
>
> Suppose (i) and take $g \in G$. By assumption we have $gH \subseteq Hg$, which means that for every $h \in H$ there is $h' \in H$ such that $gh = h'g$, so $ghg^{-1} = h'$ and then $gHg^{-1} \subseteq H$. Also, by assumption we have $Hg \subseteq gH$, and this tells us that for every $h \in H$ there is $h' \in H$ such that $hg = gh'$, so $h = gh'g^{-1}$ and then $H \subseteq gHg^{-1}$.
>
> Now suppose (iii) and we will prove (i). For that, take $g \in G$ and observe that $gHg^{-1} \subseteq H$ means that for all $h \in H$ there exists $h' \in H$ with $ghg^{-1} = h'$, so $gh = h'g$ and this proves $gH \subseteq Hg$. Next, since we are also assuming that $g^{-1}Hg = g^{-1}H(g^{-1})^{-1} \subseteq H$, this means that for all $h \in H$ there exists $h' \in H$ with $g^{-1}hg = h'$, so $hg = gh'$ and this proves that $Hg \subseteq gH$.
>
> Finally, it is obvious that (ii) implies (iii).

Answer (score 1):

It's obviously true.  If $gH = Hg$, multiply both sides by $g^{-1}$ to get $gHg^{-1} = H$, and hence $gHg^{-1} \subseteq H$.  Since $g$ can be anything, replace $g$ by $g^{-1}$ to get $g^{-1}Hg \subseteq H$.

Comment: do the left and right multiplication hold for cosets?

Comment: @Eugene It holds for all elements of $H$, so it holds for $H$.

Comment: Yes, in fact it works for any subset of $G$.